# Detecting where to bind to receive a UDP broadcast

Tags: linux, networking, socket, udp

I'm writing an application that needs to capture and print UDP broadcasts. The network interface in use is:

```
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.10.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.10.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:feb9:b18c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:b9:b1:8c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

Packets are received and printed successfully for the states below.

```
$ sudo lsof -P -iUDP
python3   5496            root    3u  IPv4  54675      0t0  UDP *:67

$ sudo strace python3 main.py 2>&1 | grep bind
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(67), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
```

I need to have the binding to a specific address and not all addresses `0.0.0.0`. So I change the script to bind to mimic the `0.0.0.0` behavior and loop and bind to any possible address in the subnet. Result being:

```
$ sudo lsof -P -iUDP
python3   5472            root    3u  IPv4  52392      0t0  UDP 192.168.10.0:67 
python3   5472            root    4u  IPv4  52393      0t0  UDP user-VirtualBox:67 
python3   5472            root    6u  IPv4  52647      0t0  UDP 192.168.10.255:67
```

However, the app still doesn't print anything.

**Question**

Is there a difference between binding to `0.0.0.0` as opposed to binding to every possible bindable address that could cause a package not to be passed to the userspace application?

Answer (score 1):

DHCP clients send requests to `255.255.255.255.67` so listening to something that can receive those would be beneficial for a DHCP server. In testing, something bound to the equivalent of your `192.168.10.255:bootps` listen address **does not** see those packets.

What compels the need to bind to something that is not `*:67`?

Comment: Updated the question to make it clearer. The `bootps` is just a name resolution done by `lsof`. It was port `67`.